# Can I copy my site to another domain and put wordpress theme on it?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am working on a site, and the client wants me to start from scratch with a new theme. They are using wordpress but don't like the theme. They still want the info, but they want me to use a different theme and make it look nicer.

They set me up with a testing server so I don't wreck the current site, but they hadn't transferred the content over, is there an easy way to do that? It'd be nice if I din't have to reinsert everything.

Comment: I dont know if you are talking about wordpress.org or wordpress.com.. if you are talking about wordpress.org with custom theme, I highly recommend using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ but you will need ftp access. It will unpack the files from the old site and update the url's in the database automatically!

Comment: It's wordpress.org! That plugin sounds really handy! Although I'm a little skeptical seeing all the warning telling noobs (me being one) not to mess with it ha @msbodetti

Answer (score 1):

You can dump the wordpress database and execute it on the new staging website this way you will keep every data.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, assuming you're newer to this it's easiest to use phpMyAdmin to view the database.

1. Click the 'Export' tab to export the database in SQL format.
2. Create a new database on the staging server with the same name as the .sql file.
3. On the new database in phpMyAdmin, click 'Import' and upload the .sql file.
4. Make sure the credentials all match in your wp-config.php file.

Answer (score 1):

The best and most easiest way to do this by using a well known plugin called `Duplicator`
Here is the link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/
This plugin will help you to create a duplicate version of the current site very easily.
Hope this helps :)